# How to add JDBC-supported database (Informix) into korma

Tags: clojure, korma

What steps do I need to take to allow my Informix JDBC driver to be a supported database in korma? Informix has a jdbc driver, and I have tested with the driver's demo Java programs. My connection parameters work.

I've gone ahead and started a Clojure project, but I'm stuck on what to try even to get an error, so I can move forward from there, let alone connecting.

My Informix JDBC driver 3.50 is in maven

```
mvn install:install-file \
-DgroupId=com.informix \
-DartifactId=ifxjdbc \
-Dversion=3.50 \
-Dfile=/opt/IBM/Informix_JDBC_Driver/lib/ifxjdbc.jar \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

The following example is for postgres. I want to do this for Informix. I am wondering what I have to do so that I can create a connection for the Informix database using something similar to

```
(defdb prod (postgres {:db "korma"
                       :user "korma"
                       :password "kormapass"
                       ;; optional keys
                       :host "myhost"
                       :port "4567"
                       :delimiters ""}))
```

I am pretty sure I cannot just use "informix" in place of postgres in the example above, and magic will happen. I am just puzzled as to what defintions to create. Any help or pointers to examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `classname` and `subprotocol` attributes:

```
(def db-config {:classname "com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
                :subprotocol "informix-sqli"
                :subname (format "//%s:1533/%s" 
                                 "123.45.67.89"
                                 "testDB:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver")
                :user "user"
                :password "password"})

(defdb db db-config)
```

Take a look at the different definitions [in the source code](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/master/src/korma/db.clj#L83-L181), `postgres` is just a shorthand for those attributes. Even if there's no `informix` predefined function you can roll your own.

According [to this doc](http://ict.udlap.mx/people/roberto/jdbcis341/docsAndothers/doc/release/program.fm1.html) driver name is `com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver`, you can also check there for database URIs:

```
The following example shows a database URL that connects 
to a database called testDB:

jdbc:informix-sqli://123.45.67.89:1533/testDB:INFORMIXSERVER=myserver;
user=rdtest;password-test
```

Also remember to add the proper dependency information to your `project.clj` file:

```
 :dependencies [...
                [com.informix.jdbc/com.springsource.com.informix.jdbc "3.0.0.JC3"]
                ...
```

And the springsource repositories for that dependency to be found:

```
  :repositories [["springsource-release" "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"]
                 ["springsource-external" "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"]]
```

Comment: How do I find the classname of my driver? Is this it com/informix/jdbc/IfxDriver.class ? Then, I'd agree with you I might have a shot at using postgres as a "template" in place of Informix.

Comment: According to the docs I've linked the classname is com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver

Comment: I'm still confused. If I am supposed to be using the informix jdbc driver, then I'm getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://steamboy:(:port opts)/stores7/ministores

Comment: what subprotocol you have specified? it should be `informix-cli` please check updated `db-config`

Comment: sorry it's informix-sqli, please also correct your port number to 1533 you have the string `(:port opts)` right now and it's going to fail

Comment: Thanks for the format call. I fixed that. I'm still getting not known driver with these parameters {:database stores7/ministores, :password 1234, :username ox, :port 1498, :server steamboy, :host steamboy} and here is the error No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli://steamboy:1498/stores7/ministores:INFORMIXSERVER=steamboy ministores.dbs is really at /home/cnorton/stores7, and the java demo code can find it.

Comment: The url format is ok, I guess your problem is you have not added the proper dependency in the project.clj, please check updated answer